# Modal With Button Add New Row (ONE ROW EVERY CLICK)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I having issue with modal in headers. When i click header "Safety", it open safety's modal and have manage to add item ONE ROW EVERY CLICK, which is great. When i duplicate my codes for second header, which is "Operate". The issue started. 
After i open Safety's modal, added new item and close the modal, I open Operate's modal and add new item. The new item i added is not ONE ROW EVERY CLICK, it added TWO Row EVERY CLICK and sometimes THREE ROW EVERY CLICK.

Please help.

```js
// Get the  that opens the Safety NewsFeed
var s_news = document.getElementById('s_news');
var safety = document.getElementById('Safety');
safety.onclick = function() {
  s_news.style.display = "block";
  $('.AddNew').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    row.find('input').val('');
    $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
    $('input[type="button"]', row).removeClass('AddNew').addClass('RemoveRow').val('Remove item');
  });

  $('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var snews_span = document.getElementsByClassName("s_newsclose")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
snews_span.onclick = function() {
  s_news.style.display = "none";
}
// Close Safety NewsFeed
window.addEventListener("click", function(s_newsevent) {
  if (s_newsevent.target == s_news) {
    s_news.style.display = "none";
  }
});
///
// Get the  that opens the Quality Internal NewsFeed
var qi_news = document.getElementById('qi_news');
var qualityint = document.getElementById('QualityInt');
qualityint.onclick = function() {
  qi_news.style.display = "block";
  $('.AddNew').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    row.find('input').val('');
    $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
    $('input[type="button"]', row).removeClass('AddNew').addClass('RemoveRow').val('Remove item');
  });

  $('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var qinews_span = document.getElementsByClassName("qi_newsclose")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
qinews_span.onclick = function() {
  qi_news.style.display = "none";
}
// Close Safety NewsFeed
window.addEventListener("click", function(qi_newsevent) {
  if (qi_newsevent.target == qi_news) {
    qi_news.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
/* News Feed (background) */

.s_news,
.qi_news {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.headercolor {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}


/* The Newsfeed Close Button */

.s_newsclose,
.qi_newsclose {
  color: #aaa;
  float: left;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <h2 style="font-size:1.5rem" id=Safety>Safety</h2>
  <h2 style="font-size:1.5rem" id=QualityInt>Operate</h2>

  <div id="s_news" class="s_news">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class=headercolor>ISSUE</td>
        <td class=headercolor>ACTION</td>
        <td class=headercolor>Add/Remove Item</td>
      </tr> <span class="s_newsclose">&times;</span>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='Add New'></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='Add New'></td>
        <td><input type='button' class='AddNew' value='Add new item'></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="qi_news" class="qi_news">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class=headercolor>ISSUE</td>
        <td class=headercolor>ACTION</td>
        <td class=headercolor>Add/Remove Item</td>
      </tr> <span class="qi_newsclose">&times;</span>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='Add New'></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='Add New -->'></td>
        <td><input type='button' class='AddNew' value='Add new item'></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't find the problem but it would seem that the "Add new item" action is being executed more than once, one extra time each click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine the code nested within the `safety.onclick` code block.  *Each time* you click "Safety", you're binding a jQuery `click()` event handler to all elements that have a class attribute of `AddNew`.  You can see this for yourself in the code snippet you provide.  Click the header, and immediately close it.  Repeat two more times.  Now when you click the "Add Item" button you'll see that *three* new rows display.

Also, notice how the effect you want to achieve is the same for each of your divs.  I would recommend a more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach to your code here.  Consider an alternative solution where your jQuery event bindings utilize the `.on()` method and are not nested within the vanilla `onclick` handler.

```
$('#s_news, #qi_news').on('click', '.AddNew', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    row.find('input').val('');
    $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
    $('input[type="button"]', row)
        .removeClass('AddNew')
        .addClass('RemoveRow')
        .val('Remove item');
});

$('#s_news, #qi_news').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Here's an example of implementing the add/remove event handling code: https://jsfiddle.net/v5r2f913

One more bit of general commentary on the provided code sample: since you are using jQuery, you may consider just using that library's selectors and event model, rather than a mixture of jQuery and vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get you codes to work, can you please help ?

Comment: @MarkKho Here's an example of implementing just the add/remove event handling code: https://jsfiddle.net/v5r2f913/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your **.AddNew** class is getting call more than once. Just change the name of the class that targets the click event on both (Safety and Operate). Example: change the first class to **".AddNew1"** and the second one to **".AddNew2"**.

**Here's a working solution**. Hope it helps!

```js
// Get the  that opens the Safety NewsFeed
var s_news = document.getElementById('s_news');
var safety = document.getElementById('Safety');
safety.onclick = function() {
  s_news.style.display = "block";
  $('.AddNew1').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    row.find('input').val('');
    $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
    $('input[type="button"]', row).removeClass('AddNew').addClass('RemoveRow').val('Remove item');
  });

  $('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var snews_span = document.getElementsByClassName("s_newsclose")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
snews_span.onclick = function() {
  s_news.style.display = "none";
}
// Close Safety NewsFeed
window.addEventListener("click", function(s_newsevent) {
  if (s_newsevent.target == s_news) {
    s_news.style.display = "none";
  }
});
///
// Get the  that opens the Quality Internal NewsFeed
var qi_news = document.getElementById('qi_news');
var qualityint = document.getElementById('QualityInt');
qualityint.onclick = function() {
  qi_news.style.display = "block";
  
  $('.AddNew2').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    row.find('input').val('');
    $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
    $('input[type="button"]', row).removeClass('AddNew').addClass('RemoveRow').val('Remove item');
  });

  $('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var qinews_span = document.getElementsByClassName("qi_newsclose")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
qinews_span.onclick = function() {
  qi_news.style.display = "none";
}
// Close Safety NewsFeed
window.addEventListener("click", function(qi_newsevent) {
  if (qi_newsevent.target == qi_news) {
    qi_news.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
.s_news,
.qi_news {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.headercolor {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}


/* The Newsfeed Close Button */

.s_newsclose,
.qi_newsclose {
  color: #aaa;
  float: left;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 style="font-size:1.5rem" id=Safety>Safety</h2>
  <h2 style="font-size:1.5rem" id=QualityInt>Operate</h2>

  <div id="s_news" class="s_news">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class=headercolor>ISSUE</td>
        <td class=headercolor>ACTION</td>
        <td class=headercolor>Add/Remove Item</td>
      </tr> <span class="s_newsclose">&times;</span>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='Add New'></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='Add New'></td>
        <td><input type='button' class='AddNew1' value='Add new item'></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="qi_news" class="qi_news">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class=headercolor>ISSUE</td>
        <td class=headercolor>ACTION</td>
        <td class=headercolor>Add/Remove Item</td>
      </tr> <span class="qi_newsclose">&times;</span>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='Add New'></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='Add New -->'></td>
        <td><input type='button' class='AddNew2' value='Add new item'></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
```

Comment: Henry, It works for A to B or B to A . But it is not working for A-B-A or B-A-B.

Comment: Assuming A is Safety and B is Operate.